# Cant create a table called address in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, erd

Evening everyone... I used oracle data modeller to create a schema and tried to implement it  in apex using the following sql

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESSES
(
addressID      VARCHAR2 (15 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
address_line1  VARCHAR2 NOT NULL ,
address_line2  VARCHAR2 ,
city           VARCHAR2 (20 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
post_code      VARCHAR2 (10 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
OWNERS_ownerID VARCHAR2 (15 CHAR) NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE ADDRESSES ADD CONSTRAINT ADDRESSES_PK PRIMARY KEY ( addressID ) ;
```

When i run it in sql command it give me `ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis`
And when I ran everything together in script it gives `DROP TABLE ADDRESSES CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Any ideas guys what am I doing wrong?

Comment: mention size for all varchars

Comment: @BhupeshC gosh man thanks it worked but im still getting `DROP TABLE ADDRESSES CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` in script.... post it as an answer mate please Ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working missed character in domain for varchar here is the code

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESSES
(
addressID      VARCHAR2 (15 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
address_line1  VARCHAR2 (30 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
address_line2  VARCHAR2 (30 CHAR) ,
city           VARCHAR2 (20 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
post_code      VARCHAR2 (10 CHAR) NOT NULL ,
OWNERS_ownerID VARCHAR2 (15 CHAR) NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE ADDRESSES ADD CONSTRAINT ADDRESSES_PK PRIMARY KEY ( addressID ) ;
```

Thanks to @BhupeshC